# Custom UITableViewCell Editing Mode Icons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Let me get disclosure out of the way first: I'm just beginning iOS programming, furthermore I am a student and this is homework.

The project I am currently doing requires the creation of a Table View with custom cells in it. I've achieved that. However, it also requires putting the Table View into edit mode for deleting stuff (i.e. making the red icon thingies appear). That is something I haven't achieved. Here is the code directly used to change the editing mode. (view is the tv, it's wired to a UIButton)

```
-(IBAction)toggleEdit:(id)sender
{

  if(isEditing)
  {
    NSLog(@"true");
    isEditing = false;
    [view setEditing:false];
  }
  else
  {
    NSLog(@"false");
    isEditing = true;
    [view setEditing:true];
  }
}
```

Cell Allocation code:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString* cellID = @"Cell";

  ShipCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

  if (!cell)
  {
    NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ShipCellView" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [views objectAtIndex:0];
  }


  cell.nameLabel.text = [dataController getNameAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.operatorLabel.text = [dataController getOperatorAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.flagImage.image = [dataController getFlagAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  return cell;
}
```

Relevant UIBuilder screenshots:

[image][image]

I've been through my school-appointed iOS5 textbook (building for iOS6), as well as a lot of the school videos, which say my current code will work. (which it does in terms of displaying custom cells, but not for showing the editing icons.)

Full Source (of relevant files) for sake of completion:
http://pastebin.com/upLYXz4i
The controller for the cell nib is boilerplate.

Comment: Your topic is too long for volunteers to read it all through.  Please make it shorter.

Comment: I've posted longer and gotten answers, but if it will help in this case, I just condensed the question post a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from me using a pseudo-reserved keyword for one of my outlets; changing it resolved the problem.

To be specific, I named an outlet view, which isn't a great thing to do.